# Opening Windows within a TabGroup on iOS with Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm re-visiting an old app created with Classic (not Alloy) and need to remove the deprecated window:url functionality, but in this new update I need to add some navigation windows inside the tabGroup.

I understand I need to create a global that I can call so I can open the new window inside the correct tab.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

So I have two questions really.

1. What is the best way to import another JS file (in Classic) to replace the window URL method?

and

2. How do I go about setting a global up (again, in Classic) so I can open and close windows within my tabGroup?

Here is my tab setup in tabs.js (with URL's to my other JS files in the window)

```
    // create tab group
var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
    tintColor: '#FFF',
    barColor: '#ff5700',
    tabsTintColor:'#333333',
    navTintColor: '#FFF',
    tabsBackgroundColor :'#ff5700'
});


// Assign windows & tabs

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'#fff', barColor:'#ff5700', url:'team.js', title:'Team', navTintColor:'#FFF', titleAttributes:{color: '#FFF'}});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ window:win1, icon:'images/team.png', title:'Team', titleColor:'#FFF', activeTitleColor:'#333', activeIcon:'images/team.png', activeIconIsMask:true, iconIsMask:false});
var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'#fff', barColor:'#ff5700', url:'league.js', title:'League', navTintColor:'#FFF', titleAttributes:{color: '#FFF'}});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ window:win2, icon:'images/league.png', title:'League', titleColor:'#FFF', activeTitleColor:'#333', activeIcon:'images/league.png', activeIconIsMask:true, iconIsMask:false});
var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'#fff', barColor:'#ff5700', url:'fixtures.js', title:'Fixtures', navTintColor:'#FFF', titleAttributes:{color: '#FFF'}});
var tab3 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ window:win3, icon:'images/fixtures.png', title:'Fixtures', titleColor:'#FFF', activeTitleColor:'#333', activeIcon:'images/fixtures.png', activeIconIsMask:true, iconIsMask:false});
var win4 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'#fff', barColor:'#ff5700', url:'players.js', title:'Players', navTintColor:'#FFF', titleAttributes:{color: '#FFF'}});
var tab4 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ window:win4, icon:'images/players.png', title:'Players', titleColor:'#FFF', activeTitleColor:'#333', activeIcon:'images/players.png', activeIconIsMask:true, iconIsMask:false});
var win5 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'#fff', barColor:'#ff5700', url:'more.js', title:'More', navTintColor:'#FFF', titleAttributes:{color: '#FFF'}});
var tab5 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ window:win5, icon:'images/more.png', title:'More', titleColor:'#FFF', activeTitleColor:'#333', activeIcon:'images/more.png', activeIconIsMask:true, iconIsMask:false});


tabGroup.addTab(tab1);  
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);  
tabGroup.addTab(tab3);
tabGroup.addTab(tab4);
tabGroup.addTab(tab5);


tabGroup.open();
```

Here is how I want to call in another window within one of my tabs. I've chopped tons of code out of this as you don't need to see all of it!

```
var createWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    title: 'Create League'
});

createButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    tabGroup.activeTab.open(createWin);
});
```

I need to get **tabGroup.activeTab.open(createWin);** into scope somehow!

Any help would be appreciated!

Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it global with `Ti.App.tabGroup` and then `Ti.App.tabGroup.activeTab.open(createWin);`

Answer (score 0):

First, your windows could be in another file as a CommonJS module.
Something like this:

```
//tabTeam.js file

function tabTeam(){
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'yellow'
    });
    //put the code of your window here as usually

    //don't forget to return the window
    return win;
}
module.exports = tabTeam;
```

then, for the tabgroup, as Sebastian said, you should go for the Ti.App global properties, like:

```
Ti.App.tabgroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({}
    backgroundColor:'white'
);
```

and to ask for the window, do like this:

```
var teamWindow = require("tabTeam")();
```

and add it to the tabgroup:

```
var tab1 = Ti.UI.createTab({
    icon:'asdasd.png',
    window:teamWindow
});
```

and open the tabgroup with the tabgroup.open().

If you are inside a window, and want to open another window in the same tab, with the cool iOS navigation animation, do:

```
btOpenWindow.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var profileWindow = require("profile")(parameters);
    Ti.App.tabgroup.activeTab.open(profileWindow);
});
```

That's all! Let me know if works =)

Comment: Great! I'm going to give it a try, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Create global variable in app.js

```
var tabGroupGlobal;
```

In your current window create tabgroup and assign that to in Global variable

```
var tabGroup = Ti.UI.createTabGroup({
    tintColor: '#FFF',
    barColor: '#ff5700',
    tabsTintColor:'#333333',
    navTintColor: '#FFF',
    tabsBackgroundColor :'#ff5700'
});

tabGroupGlobal = tabGroup;
```

Now you can use tabGroupGlobal in any window.

```
btOpenWindow.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
    tabGroupGlobal.activeTab.open(newWindow);
});
```

I think this may help you. If anything wrong or suggestion please tell me.